# How to do incremental/sync image backup of full machine in linux using dd command?

Tags: linux, backup, iso

Using `dd` I am able to do an image backup. But I wish to do an incremental/sync backup.

With `dd`, I am able to create a new image file only. It is a time consuming process.  I have 2TB of data in my machine.

Is there a way to do an incremental backup?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Use `rsync` for incremental backup.

Comment: If you want some software, ask here. If you want to use `dd`, as on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible -- `dd` can't do an incremental backup, anymore than it can do word processing, play videos, or surf the web.  `dd` is a [software tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_tool), (think of it like a hammer, or a wrench, or a pair of pliers), designed to do one thing, and do it well.

Incremental backups depend on [metadata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata#Definition), specifically [timestamps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_system#Metadata), and that requires a tool that can read and interpret a file system's timestamps and [attributes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_attribute).  There are many tools that can do that, see these questions for help:

- [What backup tool should I use for easy incremental backups?](https://serverfault.com/q/308104/355519)
- [Easy incremental backups to an external hard drive](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/553/165517)
- [Comparison of backup tools](https://askubuntu.com/q/2596/561230)

---

Note: Still, one might doggedly ask why can't `dd` only copy over the new or changed sectors and blocks.  But `dd` is a simple kind of tool, it's not able to know what's different.  Sectors and blocks have no timestamps or metadata, so there's nothing to help `dd` know what's new.  `dd` can't know what's changed either, not without comparing a new block to an old block, but `dd` doesn't know how to compare blocks.

But suppose, for the sake of argument, `dd` could read a backup disk image ***X*** and compare it to the present disk ***Y***.  So let's say `dd` would read a block from *X*, then the corresponding block from *Y*, and compare them, and if they were the same, copy the new block to incremental backup file ***Z***.  But there's no point to that, since:

- the purpose of the incremental backup was to save time backing up a hard drive.  But with this method, `dd` still has to read the entirety of disk ***X***, (plus all of backup ***Y***), which would probably take *more* time.
- even though one might correctly argue that at least such a method would save some time *writing* the backup file *Z*, and some space storing it, this would be "reinventing the wheel" since other tools already read two files and create a *diff* file of what's changed.  Such as: `bsdiff`, `radiff2`, `hexdiff`, `xdelta3`, `vbindiff`, *etc*...